# Keep SESSION php after 3° pages refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

i have a issue with my SESSIONS, on the first page the user clicks on a anchor, then if the user is logged in will be redirected without problem, but if not, first he will pass through login page, but when the user reach thelogin page, the variables are missing. (The login page occurs after the redirect page). So i have saved the SESSIONS with $_GET parameters.

How i can keep the current SESSIONS to redirect the user after the login?

Thanks!

**EDITED**

Page: retailer.php (this page is where its fired the parameters)

```
<a href="/go2store.php?rid=<?php echo $row['slug_title']; ?>&c=<?php echo     $row_coupons['coupon_id']; ?>" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='<?php echo $row_coupons['logout_url']; ?>';" target="_blank">
```

Page: go2store.php (this page is where i'm saving the SESSION)

```
$_SESSION["myCupon"] = "/go2store.php?rid=".$_GET['rid']."&c=".$_GET['c'];
```

Page: redirect.php (This page its checking if the user is logged in, if yes, redirect to the URL on the SESSION, if not will send to login.php)

Page: login.php (here i have this on top of the code)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["myCupon"] = "/go2store.php?rid=".$_POST['rid']."&c=".$_POST['c'];
```

But it comes empty, its not returning any values after the redirect.php page.

Comment: Please provide examples of the code you're using on the login page. Without more info, you won't get as solution.

Comment: You need `session_start();` inside all your pages used (if it's not already in all of your pages), and using the same session name respectively.

Comment: Hi guys, just edited with the current code, sorry. Also, on the top of every page have session_start(); and the requested SESSION. i dont know why its lost after redirect check for logged in users.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by a user in the comments, you need to include:

```
session_start();
```

At the top of each page to carry session variables across pages, otherwise it won't recognise  the vars you set initially.

We don't know how you're organising your code, but this needs to be present both before and after potential login.

You can easily set/get `$_SESSION` variables prior to login or indeed set/get upon login from other vars you might use in pages that aren't yet authenticated.

Comment: Hey, i do have session_start(); everywhere and also i do call the SESSIONS, but i have one question, its better to save the SESSION into a variable and then call that variable or call the SESSION itself?